# Jupyter notebook exported in pdf via LaTex do not show/support Banglafont from Fedora 38

Tags: linux, jupyter-notebook, latex, fedora, bangla-font

I wanted to export my notebook in pdf format vai LaTex. When I downloaded the pdf I couldn't the markdown text in Bangla font. evrything was fine but the fonts were missing.

I have installed major bangla fonts in my fedora 38
full latex installed

How can make make changes to see the bangla text of notebook exported in pdf?

I tried to install bangla fonts
installed full latex